# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when returning JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, endpoint

I've got some jQuery that is successful in hitting an endpoint, here's my code

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://url.that-works.com/env/Development/GetDevs/",
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    data: "callback=?"
})
.done(function (data) {
    alert("success");
})
;
```

The code returns the following JSON response - which I can see in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
{
"developments": [
    {
        "name": "h2010 Ph2"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Meadows Ph2"
    },
    {
        "name": "h2010 Ph3"
    },
    {
        "name": "h2010 Ph4"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Meadows Ph3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've checked that this is valid JSON being returned, but I keep getting an error message: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*

I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here or why I'm getting this message, any guidance would be really appreciated.

bengrah.

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: Not returning application/json as Mime type ??

Comment: @vogomatix — Can't be.  `dataType: "json",` causes jQuery to ignore the Content-Type

Comment: Whats the line number? Is it telling you were the syntax error occurred and what the trace is?

Comment: I've just built a local test cause using that code (and substituting my own URL) and cannot reproduce the problem. Whatever it is, it isn't expressed in your question.

Comment: pay attention on you `data` param sen as GET request ... you can add this string to your URL if needed, but you can try without it. Norrmaly you can see where the exception happened ... so you can see more info why it happens.

Comment: @Reflective — Removing it doesn't make a difference. The code works with it present in my tests.

Comment: Then I don't see any problem with code and json data which is valid.

Comment: not sure what's the response header, but it should be `application/json` - it's important.

Comment: @Reflective — As I said, I can't reproduce the problem locally. Sending the correct content type is best practise, but as I mentioned earlier, `dataType: "json"`, causes jQuery to ignore it.

Comment: My guess is what is being returned is not exactly what is in the code above.

Comment: jQuery version? there are a lot of  changes in AJAX in different versions. Can we know what's the jQuery version?

Comment: @epascarello I get it on the response

Comment: @vogomatix Line number is 1, it says it's part of a jQuery response, it looks like this jQuery18406445654265099913_1319844792316:1 (line number

Comment: @Quentin The endpoint I'm hitting is in the cloud, not sure if that's got an impact on it here.

Comment: Like I said, I _do_ see the JSON on the response, but I'm not able to use the response in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured out the answer.

In our case, we were using a middleware appliance that generates the above URL/orchestration the script hits to get the JSON and so on. What we were trying to do was use a JSONP request to get at this info, but the orchestration returns JSON that **wasn't wrapped in a function**, which is where our problem lies.

Instead, we changed it to a standard *JSON get* request, which then caused the *Access-Control-Allow-Origins error* (good link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)). At this point, we added the *Access-Control-Allow-Origins* setting to the orchestration/server side - then we were able to get the JSON back in a usable format successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery docs you can find the following:

'Cross-domain `json` requests are converted to `jsonp` unless the request includes `jsonp: false` in its request options.'

So probably you are making a cross domain call and it is converted to `jsonp` because you have specified `dataType: 'json'`.

When in JSONP mode, jQuery looks for such kind of response:

```
jQuery18406445654265099913_1319844792316({
"developments": [
    {
        "name": "h2010 Ph2"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Meadows Ph2"
    },
    {
        "name": "h2010 Ph3"
    },
    {
        "name": "h2010 Ph4"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Meadows Ph3"
    }
  ]
})
```

but not a JSON string, so you are getting an error during the convertion.
JSONP expects a javascript, not a string.
If you take a look at the jQuery code you can make it more clear for you, but that's in general.

Comment: @Reflective should I change my datatype to _jsonp_ - I'll take a look at the jQuery docs for this as well.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you change it from JSON to JSONP, it will be executed as JSONP because it is cross domain call, but if you have to be correct in your code, change it to JSONP because it is actually a JSONP call.

Comment: Probably if you change it to `jsonp` it will work, but my advice is to remove  `data: "callback=?"` - callback function will be passed automatically when you use `datatype: 'jsonp'`

Comment: @Reflective Changed the dataType: "jsonp", removed the data: "callback=?" but still getting the same error. Will continue looking at the docs.